# how to share my flutter app link with my referaal code on whastapp to another user,when that user click on that link link user redirect to play store

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, deep-linking

i want to share my flutter app link with my referral code on WhatsApp to another user,when that user click on that link if the app in not install that time link redirect to play store and if app is already installed that time app in directly open ,and when user open register page that time my referral code automatically fulfill textbox

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by Firebase Dynamic links
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links

Comment: can you provide me some example ?

Comment: You can follow the docs it's pretty straight forward
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/dynamic-links/overview/

Comment: Dude, this package is deprecated!